# Scaling striped background in non-rectangular shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the design depicted in the image below with pure CSS, in which a striping pattern casts down at an angle from a similarly colored block of content, but outside its swath the background retains its base color.

I was able to achieve the desired effect of the striped background by a mix of linear gradients with percentage stops, the background-size property, and rgba colors--the stripes in the original mockup are sub-pixel width, which I simulated by lowering opacity--but of course by default this pattern is filling the entire rectangle of its section, when I would like it to be limited to a parallelogram that reaches down from the right-hand div, but which does not interrupt the flow of content.

I want to avoid simply setting the background to an image of the desired result, because I am designing this site in a mobile-first responsive fashion, so I need the smooth scaling of a pure CSS solution.

I have been toying with the transform:skewX property, and have found it works provided you include a wrapper for unskewing the contents of the block, but the problem remains that while I now have the angled boundaries I want, I don't know how to make them conform to the right-hand div above without compromising the flow I have in mind.

[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/68a39uy8/) is the JSFiddle in which I've implemented the first suggestion, but as you can see, this solution is non-responsive. The current iteration of the striped background is, in keeping with the suggestion, a :before pseudo-element with the following styling.

```
#striped::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  right: 130px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  );
  background-size: 100% 4px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>As we don't have a code to work from, I here show a proof of concept how one can do</strike>

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  right: 130px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #8cf,
    #8cf 50%,
    transparent 50%,
    transparent
  );
  background-size: 100% 6px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Updated based on comment and question edit

The major part was to move the striped pseudo to the `p` so it will size with it, and here is an updated version, using your code base, where I updated/added these rules (and added a `div` container in markup).

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#preceding p {
  position: relative;
}
#preceding p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%,-50vw);
  transform-origin: left top;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  );
  background-size: 14px 100%;
  margin:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e0dabf;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville";
}

p a {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#preceding {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

#preceding h2 {
  flex: 3;
  font-family: "Libre Franklin";
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: #5da5b6;
}

#preceding p {
  display: block;
  flex: 7;
  background-color: #5da5b6;
  color: #d5caa2;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

#preceding p a {
  color: #f2da83;
}

#striped {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  padding:0;
}

#striped h2 {
  flex:1 100%;
}

#striped div {
  flex:1 50%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#preceding p {
  position: relative;
}
#preceding p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 500vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%,-50vw);
  transform-origin: left top;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 50%, rgba(93, 165, 182, 0.3) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  );
  background-size: 14px 100%;
  margin:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#further {
  margin:0;
  background-color:#5da5b6;
}

#further h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section id="preceding">
  <h2>Content</h2>
  <p>Additional content goes here. The goal is that the striped element below should conform to the size of this element responsively without changing angle or thickness.</p>
</section>
<section id="striped">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div>
    <h3>
    Block o' Content
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
    Block o' Content
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
    Block o' Content
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
    Block o' Content
    </h3>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="further">
  <h1>
  More stuff to follow!
  </h1>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this demonstration. Having implemented it, it is as I thought non-responsive. I have attached a JSFiddle which includes the relevant bounding sections of the design for reference.

Comment: @user968270 Updated my answer

Comment: Excellent! That's the behavior I was looking for. Thank you so much.